# How to Resolve 'Serverless Function Exceeded 250 MB' Error on Vercel Deployment?

Tags: vercel

I encountered an error while deploying my project on Vercel. The error message states that one of my Serverless Functions has exceeded the unzipped maximum size of 250 MB. I need help understanding how to fix this issue and reduce the function's size to meet Vercel's limitations.

Steps Taken:

I reviewed my function's code and dependencies for any unnecessary or large elements that could be optimized.
I considered using smaller libraries or alternative packages to reduce the function's size.
I attempted to compress assets and resources used by the function to minimize their size.
I split the function into smaller units, but the issue persisted.
I explored offloading heavy computations to external services, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

I expected my project to deploy successfully on Vercel without any errors related to Serverless Function size limits.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue as you did but in my use case I was using DRF aka python, I realised that even after I uninstalled everything that made it exceed the 250 MB limit in a shell file during building, this line would appear.

> ```
> Installing required dependencies...
> ```

I realised that even uninstalling dependencies wouldn't work since it would download them again, so my solution in this case was to just to make a Github branch of the largest dependency I had and remove the dependency that was making it bloated, obviously with code changes to make it continue working, then installing that branch as a library.

In my python use case, it worked. Your mileage may vary.